# iOS Safari/Chrome scrolls to top when keyboard appears and you can't scroll to the page's top

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, virtual-keyboard

I'm developing a chat application for our network and I have the following "issue". As you can see in the screenshots, the content moves up when the keyboard appears (on iOS devices only).

If the Keyboard appears, you're not able to scroll to the top until you hide the keyboard. 
My supervisor wants me to fix this issue. You should be able to scroll to the top of the page, while the keyboard is displayed.

Have anyone an idea?

[image]
[image]

Comment: We can't help you if we don't have access to the code. Make a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: here is an example. Hope it helps you to understand my problem on iOS devices:

https://codepen.io/iamarkuslenz/full/RJmYNM?editors=1100